# Pass Custom data in PayPal form

Tags: php, paypal

I want to pass many custom data in PayPal form and get into Success Page. How can I do this?

I use input field name `custom`, but it has limitation. Please give me proper solution for this.

```
<input type="hidden" name="custom" id="custom" value="<?php $data['formdata']; ?>" />
```

This is not work for my functionality.

Comment: you can pass multiple data with separator or comma in value like value="data1~data2~data3", here separator is ~. To access passed data just use split or explode

Comment: please use pre-dev php library    "https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-php-library/tree/dev/templates" it may be helpful

Comment: Hello Omi, I pass value as you say. But it has limitation of 256 character.

Comment: Hello Rahul, I don't want to change library.

Comment: The length limit of 255 chars is set by paypal. If you need more than that, you'll have to store the data somewhere yourself, and pass a key (e.g., orderno) in the 'custom' field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is character sending limitation in paypal so one thing you can do when the paypal form is created at that time you can insert all records in temporary table and you only pass that record id in custom field and after payment will be success you can fetch that data from db and insert original data entry.